# How to force core plot library not to localize labels?

Tags: ios, localization, xamarin.ios, core-plot, label

How to stop localization from work even if i changed my region format

I am using Cpttimeformatter and i found a readonly property returns the locale identifier

```
Cpttimeformatterobj.locale.localeidentifier
```

Is there anyway to set the locale identifier to a certain region format ex:"en_US"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `locale` property is inherited from NSNumberFormatter. It has a setter, so you can create  new NSLocale object and assign it to your CPTTimeFormatter.